# How to perform xmlparsing using xmlreader for a particular section

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmlreader

The XML file structure is like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Application>
          <Tabs>
             <Tab name="1">
               <title>abcd</title>
               <description>xyz</description>
             </Tab>
             <Tab name="2">
               <title>abcde</title>
               <description>xyzw</description>
             </Tab>
          </Tabs>
         <Files>
         </Files>
    </Application>
```

I would like to read only the Tabs section using XmlReader in asp.net 2.0. The values that I'm interested in are the title and description contents. There are in total 7 tabs which can increase also later on. Hence can't iterate over a count variable with value fixed.

Comment: all the tabs have the same value for the attribute `name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use `XPathDocument`, you can try something like this.

Note: If you already have a `XmlReader` instance, instead of using `StringReader`, you can use the constructor overload that take `XmlReader`.

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<Application>
      <Tabs>
         <Tab name=""1"">
           <title>abcd</title>
           <description>xyz</description>
         </Tab>
         <Tab name=""2"">
           <title>abcd</title>
           <description>xyzw</description>
         </Tab>
      </Tabs>
     <Files>
     </Files>
</Application>";

string xpath = "/Application/Tabs/Tab/description";

XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xml));
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator nodeIterator = nav.Select(xpath);

foreach (XPathNavigator item in nodeIterator)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(inputUrl))
  {
    reader.MoveToContent();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
      {
        if (reader.Name == elementName)
        {
          XElement el = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```